# Regex works in python simulator but not in perl

Tags: python, regex, perl

Hello I´m using an online regex simulator to test that what I´m writing is correct:
I want to extract information from the following texts:

```
Test23242asdsa 800,03 23.05.19 22.05.19
Tdsadas,tsadsa test 1.020,03 23.05.19 22.05.19
Test,23242 0,03 23.05.19 22.05.19
```

I try to use the same code in perl:

```
use strict;
my $entry = 'Test23242asdsa 0,03 23.05.19 22.05.19';
my ($name, $expense, $date_expense, $date_paid) = $1, $2, $3, $4 if ($entry =~ m/^(.+)\s((?:\d+\.)?\d{1,3},\d{2})\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})$/);
print "Name: '$name', Expense: '$expense', Date: '$date_expense', Date Paid: '$date_paid' \n";
```

And if I use the same regex here:

```
https://regex101.com/
^(.+)\s((?:\d+\.)?\d{1,3},\d{2})\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})$
```

It detects de regex correctly. I though python and perl used the same regex syntax, so I don´t get what is going on.

Comment: Perl uses PCRE. Python `re` is not the same as PCRE.

Comment: @Barmar I just tried to switch it in the simulator and it still matches, while my code in perl does not

Comment: The regexp is matching, it just doesn't seem to be setting any of the variables except `$name`

Comment: @Barmar but according to the simulator the groups are correctly set, and the output should go to $1, $2, $3 and $4. As far as I understand...

Comment: The problem is with how you're assigning the variables. If you put `$1`, `$2`, etc. in the print statement you see what you want.

Comment: @Barmar, No, Perl doesn't use PCRE. That's an independent regex engine library with a syntax based on the one used by Perl's regex engine (just like Python's)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regexp is fine, the problem is with how you're setting the variables.

You need to wrap `$1, $2, $3, $4` in parentheses to do list assignment, because of Perl's operator precedence.

Change it to

```
my ($name, $expense, $date_expense, $date_paid) = ($1, $2, $3, $4) if ($entry =~ m/^(.+)\s((?:\d+\.)?\d{1,3},\d{2})\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})$/);
```

[working demo](https://ideone.com/2P1Q7v)

Comment: Re "*You need to wrap $1, $2, $3, $4 in a list to do list assignment.*", You mean wrap them in parens. Parens don't create a list; they merely override precedence, which is what's required here.

Answer (score 3):

Although it might not fit into your task, Perl's match operator returns the list of captures in list context. You can then look at the variables to see if they have values.

In this example I used the `/x` flag to spread out the regex by making whitespace insignificant and allow for inline comments. It's a bit easier to read that way, and Perl is much more lenient than Python in expanding statements across lines:

```
#!perl
use strict;
my $entry = '';
my ($name, $expense, $date_expense, $date_paid) =
    $entry =~ m/
        ^
        ( .+                      )  \s  # Name
        ( (?:\d+\.)?\d{1,3},\d{2} )  \s  # Expense
        ( \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}     )  \s  # Date
        ( \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}     )      # Date Paid
        $
        /x;

if( defined $name ) {
    print <<"HERE";
Name:      $name
Expense:   $expense
Date:      $date_expense
Date Paid: $date_paid
HERE
    }
else {
    print "No match!";
    }
```

But, Perl also supports Python-style named captures. Instead of relying on the capture position in a long regex, you give each capture a name with `(?P<label>...)` (although most Perl people will leave off the `P` for just `(?<label>...)`). The capture names are keys in the `%+` hash:

```
#!perl
use strict;
my $entry = 'Test23242asdsa 800,03 23.05.19 22.05.19';
$entry =~ m/
        ^
        (?P<name>       .+                      )  \s
        (?P<expense>    (?:\d+\.)?\d{1,3},\d{2} )  \s
        (?P<date>       \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}     )  \s
        (?P<date_paid>  \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}     )
        $
        /x;

if( defined $+{name} ) {
    print <<"HERE";
Name:      $+{name}
Expense:   $+{expense}
Date:      $+{date}
Date Paid: $+{date_paid}
HERE
    }
else {
    print "No match!";
    }
```

Comment: Failed to process amount in millions.

Comment: Is the question was about naming of capture groups? I do not see it in the question. I believe that OP was happy with capture into list of variables.

Comment: If the ',,,....' present in the input data then there is a problem with the data? Don't you think so? If such data present the program must be terminated with `die` to indicate the problem.

Comment: People often don't know what's possible, and can't ask for what they don't know about. The question is specifically about getting the captures into variables and not about the particular patterns. Part of answering questions is noticing needs they don't realize they have. Simply dumping code on their stated need doesn't help that much. But, if you want to be pedantic, then your own contributions needs to be spotless, and they often are quite lacking. Again, the particulars of the match are not important for the points I make.

Comment: You brought exactly my point, that code which I did provide is not for production but some other way to capture input data. I always assume a best case of scenario that input data is sanitized in advance. Yes, you code assumes validity of amount in thousands but if you took this route then amount should not be limited to only thousands, or at least in comment to the code you should mention it.

Comment: @briandfoy I have to thank you for sure. I had no idea that you could do this to have everything much more organized, and would have prevented the issue I had.

Answer (score 1):

While not directly related to your precedence-in-assignment problem, it's worth noting that a statement:

```perl
my $x if 0
```

is called *`my()` in a false conditional* and
is [prohibited as of Perl 5.30.0](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.30.0/pod/perldelta.pod#my()-in-false-conditional-prohibited).

So, in general you should avoid doing this kind of "conditional declaration":

```perl
my ($foo, $baz) = ($1, $2) if $entry =~ m/^(\w+) bar (\w+)$/
```

because it might lead to an error when the condition (the regexp match, in this case) is *false*.

For the specific case, it's much better to rely on [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy)'s advice and assign the result directly to the list of variables you want to populate. The result of the assignment can then be used in boolean context, like in the following example:

```perl
if (my ($foo, $baz) = $entry =~ m/^(\w+) bar (\w+)$/) {
   # use $foo and $baz for fun and profit...
}
```

or the following, if you're looping over lines:

```perl
while (defined(my $entry = <$fh>)) {
   my ($foo, $baz) = $entry =~ m/^(\w+) bar (\w+)$/
      or next;  # <-- executed only when the regexp match fails

   # use $foo and $baz for fun and profit...
}
```

Comment: Hello, I think this only fails in case you don´t have "=" `my $x = 1 if (0);
print("X: " . $x . "\n" );` this works for me with perl 5.30

Comment: You are so right, because they didn't manage to fatalize it (https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/16702#issuecomment-544098127). I don't know if someone will address it in the future and possibly turn also assignment in a fatal error - as a personal discipline, I stay away from this construct!

Answer (score -1):

Why not to try something of this kind?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = qr/(\D+|\S+) ([\d,\.]+) ([\d\.]+) ([\d\.]+)/;
my @data;

while(<DATA>) {
    next unless /$re/;
    push @data, { name => $1, amount => $2, date_exp => $3, date_paid => $4 };
}

printf " %-20s | %10s | %-8s | %-8s |\n", qw/Name Amount Expense Paid/;
print  '-' x 58 . "\n";

for my $rec (@data) {
    printf " %-20s | %10s | %8s | %8s |\n", @$rec{qw/name amount date_exp date_paid/} ;
}

__DATA__
Test23242asdsa 800,03 23.05.19 22.05.19
Tdsadas,tsadsa test 1.020,03 23.05.19 22.05.19
Test,23242 0,03 23.05.19 22.05.19
```

Output

```
 Name                 |     Amount | Expense  | Paid     |
----------------------------------------------------------
 Test23242asdsa       |     800,03 | 23.05.19 | 22.05.19 |
 Tdsadas,tsadsa test  |   1.020,03 | 23.05.19 | 22.05.19 |
 Test,23242           |       0,03 | 23.05.19 | 22.05.19 |
```